# Ошибка при попытке получить данные из файла .ini

Tags: python, python-3.x, ini

Имеется следующий кусок кода:

```
        self.file_names = []
        self.directory_task_number = []

        config = ConfigParser()
        config.read(self.directory_task_number)

        # Переменные для определения типа загружаемых данных
        self.task1_type = config['task_text'].get('text')

        for file in os.listdir(self.directory_task):
            if file.endswith(".ini"):
                self.directory_task_number.append(os.path.join(self.directory_task, file))
                self.file_names.append(
                    (os.path.basename(os.path.join(self.directory_task, file)).split('.')[0]).split("_")[0])

        for i in range(0, len(self.file_names)):
            if self.file_names[i] == "1":
                pass
```

В котором я хочу загрузить данные из файла `.ini`, но выдается следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/PyCharm/PyCharmProject/projectSAFTD_x32/OrbitTeacher/OrbitTeacherTaskL.py", line 322, in <module>
    w = MainWindow()
  File "G:/PyCharm/PyCharmProject/projectSAFTD_x32/OrbitTeacher/OrbitTeacherTaskL.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.setting()
  File "G:/PyCharm/PyCharmProject/projectSAFTD_x32/OrbitTeacher/OrbitTeacherTaskL.py", line 84, in setting
    self.task()
  File "G:/PyCharm/PyCharmProject/projectSAFTD_x32/OrbitTeacher/OrbitTeacherTaskL.py", line 94, in task
    self.task_planned()
  File "G:/PyCharm/PyCharmProject/projectSAFTD_x32/OrbitTeacher/OrbitTeacherTaskL.py", line 312, in task_planned
    self.task123_type = config['task_text'].get('text')
  File "G:\PyCharm\Python_x32\Python_3_8_10\lib\configparser.py", line 960, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'task_text'
```

В списке программа получается значение директории для открытие нужного файла
Файл конфигурации:

```
[task_text]
text = ЗАДАНИЕ
```

**UPD:**
если упростить задачу и оставить только часть с файлом, то получается так:

```
# Поделючение библиотеки для работы файлов конфигурации
from configparser import ConfigParser

directory = "G:\PyCharm\PyCharmProject\projectSAFTD_x32\OrbitTeacher/task/first_test/1_123.ini"
config = ConfigParser()
config.read(directory)

number = config['task_text'].get('text')
print(number)
```

И ошибка изменится:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/PyCharm/PyCharmProject/projectSAFTD_x32/Hi_Tech_2022_2/main3.py", line 9, in <module>
    config.read(directory)
  File "G:\PyCharm\Python_x32\Python_3_8_10\lib\configparser.py", line 697, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "G:\PyCharm\Python_x32\Python_3_8_10\lib\configparser.py", line 1017, in _read
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
  File "G:\PyCharm\Python_x32\Python_3_8_10\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 33: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Покажите в вопросе и сам конфиг файл как выглядит. Похоже, там нет в корне `task_text`.

Comment: @CrazyElf вставил содержимое файла

Comment: А, ну похоже проблема в кодировке. Какая ОС у вас и в какой кодировке записан конфиг? Поэкспериментируйте - попробуйте записать конфиг в `UTF-8`, либо в `cp1251`, если `Windows`, хотя не факт. И после чтения конфига (когда прочитается нормально) сделайте `print(config.sections())`

Comment: @CrazyElf сейчас попробую, у меня стоит Windows 10

Comment: @CrazyElf как решить проблему с кодировкой я понял, файлы которые созданы в ручную он не воспринимает, нужно только генерировать их. А вот с тем, что он так и не видит содержимое файла нет(

Comment: @CrazyElf я решил проблема, не нужно самому писать эти файлы и нужно указывать полный путь до файла, если выполнить эти два условия, то тогда ошибок не будет, в выше описанном коде был файл сделанной руками, по этому он выдавал ошибку, большое спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Хм, я в `Google Colab` просто через `with open` записал `ini` файл и потом его через `ConfigParser` успешно прочитал, так что не знаю, в чём проблема с "ручной" записью )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Краткий ответ

Укажите кодировку, в которой следует прочитать файл

```py
config.read(directory, encoding="utf-8")
```

### Развернутый ответ

#### Предисловие

Сделал следующие выводы на основе предоставленной Вами `трассировки (Traceback)`:

1. Операционная система: Windows
2. Python 3.8

#### Обоснование

Обратимся к [исходному коду](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/configparser.py#L679) метода `read` модуля `configparser`, в котором обращаем внимание на аргумент по умолчанию `encoding=None`. Тут же замечаем [открытие файла](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/configparser.py#L696) с передачей именованного аргумента `encoding`

Что происходит в Вашем случае?

```py
config.read(directory)
```

В функцию [open](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open) передается аргумент `encoding` со значением `None`, т. к. в методе [read](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read) Вами он был опущен. Этот случай [описывается](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open:%7E:text=In%20text%20mode%2C%20if%20encoding%20is%20not%20specified%20the%20encoding%20used%20is%20platform%20dependent%3A%20locale.getpreferredencoding(False)%20is%20called%20to%20get%20the%20current%20locale%20encoding.) в разделе [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) документации Python следующим образом:

> In text mode, if encoding is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: locale.getpreferredencoding(False) is called to get the current locale encoding.

Т. е. Python неявно вызывает [locale.getpreferredencoding()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) для получения  кодировки. Что возвращает эта функция? Ответ ниже.

> Возвращает кодировку, используемую для текстовых данных, в соответствии с предпочтениями пользователя. Предпочтения задаются по-разному в разных системах и не всегда доступны из программы, поэтому данная функция возвращает только предположительное значение.

Посмотрим на результат функции в ОС Windows:

```py
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding()

'cp1251'
```

Из этого понятно, что Python пытался декодировать файл с помощью [Windows-1251](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251). "И что?" – спросите Вы. Загвоздка в том, что Python использует кодировку [UTF-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) [по умолчанию](https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/unicode.html#:%7E:text=UTF%2D8%20is%20one%20of%20the%20most%20commonly%20used%20encodings%2C%20and%20Python%20often%20defaults%20to%20using%20it.). Вот и вся проблема!